# Windows 10 Univeral App - Button in title bar not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to add a button to the title bar. My XAML looks like the following:

```
<Page
    x:Class="FullScreen.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FullScreen"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="TitleBar">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Application Name" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The .cs page has this code:

```
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace FullScreen
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
            Window.Current.SetTitleBar(TitleBar);
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await new MessageDialog("Click!").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The button shows up but it doesn't respond to the click event. If I comment out the two lines in the constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    //Window.Current.SetTitleBar(TitleBar);
}
```

The button is in the main body of the app and the click event works correctly. What am I missing?

Thanx,

Answer (score 9):

> I'm trying to add a button to the title bar. The button shows up but it doesn't respond to the click event.

According to the official documentation(Remarks part of [Window.SetTitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx)), this behavior is by design.

> **Input**
>   When you call this method to set a XAML UIElement as the title bar, it lets Windows handle input to the title bar UIElement the same way it handles input to the default system title bar. For example, a user can move the window by dragging the XAML UIElement, or invoke the window context menu by right-clicking it.
>   This means that your app **no longer receives pointer input** when the user interacts with the target UIElement or its children using touch, mouse, or pen. However, you must **still handle (or prevent) keyboard input**, and determine whether content in the title bar can receive focus **by tabbing to it** with the keyboard.

In order to make the button within the title bar to respond to the click event, we can **add a rectangle** for the customizing title bar in xaml page first:

```
<Grid x:Name="TitleBar">
    <!--Add a rectangle here-->
    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundElement" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Application Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then, **set the title bar to the rectangle** instead of the entire grid in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    // Set TitleBar to BackgroundElement instead of the entire grid
    // Clicks on the BackgroundElement will be treated as clicks on the title bar.
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(BackgroundElement);
}
```

Here is the official [Title bar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar) for your reference, and following is the output for the test code above:
[image]

Comment: Is the window still draggable?